# Visual Studio 2017 failing to install nuget package in .NET 4.7 project

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting the following error when attempting to install a nuget package into a standard .NET framework 4.7 project:

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3 Enterprise (latest and greatest).

Given that this is my package, I have full control over the source code. The interesting part is that I have used this package in the past with no changes in the name, but for this go round, I rebuilt it to add a feature and am now getting this error.

Even more interesting is that I have packages from the same library, with the same namespace conventions, with *longer* names, that work just fine and have installed into this same project with no problems at all.

I have already tried shrinking the package name, shrinking the class names within the package itself, cleaning out the build directory, cleaning out the package home from the nuget server (it's a local server with the latest nuget.server installed which otherwise works just fine), and even clearing out the bin directory of the project in question, clearing out ALL the bin directories of ALL the ancestors to the "offending" package, clearing out the package cache, rebooting the computer and rebuilding the entire nuget package chain from scratch, all to no avail. I was told by one of the MS MVP's that "they fixed that". Apparently not.

Any help would be appreciated here, I'm at my wit's end and have run out of ideas to try.

Thanks.

Comment: Where on your computer is the project stored? I find it best to have them in the root of the C drive otherwise I encounter this sort of problem too.

Comment: It's in the default location: c:\user\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\<a couple more directories down>, etc. I'd agree with you about the length of the name, however, as I said earlier, I have packages with even longer names than  this one that live in the same tree structure (same depth, longer names)  that work just fine and I *really* don't want to move the better part of a quarter million lines of code to a new location just because of the aberrant behavior of one package.

Comment: Moving the folder is a simple file operation, you don't have to copy it. (may be even faster if you do it from a command line). This is the most common cause and you may be affected by some target change in VS that causes a file in `obj` to have a longer name. Some folks are having problems with the name of the project file at the moment.

Comment: @Martin - Apologies for not clarifying - this structure is also reflected in TFS and my team would have to make the same changes - this would affect a boatload of code, screw up TFS (which actively hates me - I know, how can a piece of software "hate" - but it does!). In short, the "move the folder" option isn't an option. But thanks for responding...

Comment: Where exactly does the message come from? it should be associated with a file or msbuild target

Comment: @Martin - that's actually the root of my difficulty. If I knew (meaning that if nuget.exe would actually TELL me what file was the problem as opposed to just telling me "hey, there's a problem" and moving on) what file was generating the error, I could go back and review the issue. Unfortunately, nuget doesn't actually tell you what file caused the error unless there is a log I don't know about (which is possible).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, big Thank You  @danmosemsft who suggested digging around with the SysInternals process monitor. After fiddling with it for a bit, I finally figured out how to narrow the result set to just file activity. What I noticed, and the nuget engineers should TAKE NOTE of this: The problem was NOT a too-long project name, rather, nuget was attempting to update a package that was no longer there. Why it went away is a mystery yet to be solved. I normally stay out of the packages directory and do not fuss with the packages.config file. I *think* that this might have to do with my impatience waiting for VS to start, load all the goodies and then allow me to perform a "Manage NuGet packages" - update all. I remember seeing an update to either NUnit or FluentAssertions that wanted to perform some additional file activity aside from just installing the next version, a script I believe. Can't speak to it with assurance, I wasn't paying that much attention as third party updates usually "just work". I didn't see the "finished" line from NuGet so I think that was the root of my problem. Rather than wait until VS has settled down, I pushed it a bit (hey, the buttons responded so there *shouldn't* be any problems...).

As a result, the packages directory was absolutely chock full of old stuff that did NOT belong there. So, I manually cleaned up all the cruft, manually cleaned up the packages.config file, restarted VS, waited for it to settle down, performed my NuGet updates and viola! no problem - HAVING NOT CHANGED ANY OF THE ANCESTRAL PACKAGE NAMES BY EVEN A SINGLE CHARACTER.

So, what do I conclude from this? It is my belief, and the guys that actually build nuget and nuget.server should take a closer look at the errors being thrown, such that I *think* that the error is not so much a path too long error, rather it's a "hey, I didn't find the file I expected so the file name is full of junk (and probably too long now) so I'll throw an error that says it's too long and quit". It's seemingly a failure to handle a missing package/package directory that is causing this particular problem

I solved my problem by ensuring that all the package directories were clean of all junk and rebuilding from a clean source. My problem is now solved.

Thanks to all of you that responded.

Update: While the above contributed to the solution, it was NOT the answer. Here is the sequence of events that led to this problem and it's ultimate resolution.
The solution was created in the C:\User\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects directory with the specified name of AWE.Lib.ADO.MsSqlSvr.ServerEntityHandler. This worked just fine, no errors. However due to a change in naming scheme from on high, the root directory for this project was changed from "C:\User\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects" to "C:\User\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DotNet_4.7\AWE 8.x". No problem, I thought - given that a co-worker who also happens to be a MS MVP had told me that all naming length restrictions had been removed in VS 2017. So...I moved the project from it's current home to the directory specified. Compiles just fine, brings in UPDATED BUT ALREADY INSTALLED nuget packages just fine, etc.

Or so I thought. When I needed to add a NEW (one that had not been a part of the solution before) nuget package to the mix, I received the above error. Turns out that the new name of the receiving solution is a few characters longer than VS will accept - the naming length restrictions are STILL IN PLACE.

How did I finally solve the problem: After struggling with this, I threw my hands up and decided to start all over again - a true File | New. So, I started with a new solution named as follows:
"C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DotNet_4.7\AWE 8.x\AWE.Lib.ADO.MsSqlSvr.HndlrServerEntity"
THIS GENERATES AN ERROR - name too long. I wondered at Nuget's error in that it specifies that the name should be less than 248 characters in length or 260 maximum.

What I am allowed to use iaw the new solution dialog is this: "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DotNet_4.7\AWE 8.x\AWE.Lib.ADO.MsSqlSvr.HndlrServerEnt", for a total of 106 characters in length. If the directory is shortened, I can add to the length of the name. If I shorten the length of the actual solution name, again, VS'll accept it. So long as the total length of directory plus solution name is less than or equal to 106 characters, there isn't a problem.

The nasty bit comes from creating the solution in one location and having it work in all respects just fine, moving said solution to a different directory, still having it function in all respects (I did NOT need to add any new nuget packages yet), then trying to add a new nuget package to the mix after the move. THAT is what triggered the above nuget error.

So...the ultimate "fix", use a shorter name as it seems that 106 characters is the limit despite what the error messages are saying (and what the MS MVP was told/told me).

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0 is a pretty long name. Then it has subfolders and more subfolders.

Answer (score 7):

There is another reason for this error message by the compiler.
While building , make sure the source code is placed at a folder location which is less than 260 characters long.
For example, a path like `C:\Users\User\source\Services\Exp\Sample-web-application-indot-net-displaying-RestAPI\Sample-web-application-indot-net-displaying-RestAPI\SportsStore` is around 150 characters long but there are sub folders in the solution which in turn have source code files and so on.
Sometimes the overall length of the path of some files breaches the 260 character length.

I think the future versions of Visual Studio would have a bigger length allowance. Until then, we can make sure that our file names are not too long.

Comment: Yeah, the theory, according to an MS MVP friend of mine is that that problem (path length of 260) was already dealt with. He was quite astonished when I showed him that that isn't the case - the problem is still in there in some locations.

Comment: To resolve this without moving your entire source code to another folder on your hard disk, you could just map a drive to the folder (or even a parent folder containing all your repos if that's suitable), and then open the solution file in VS directly from Explorer (it can't be opened via VS itself). To map a drive to a local folder, use `net use x: \\localhost\c$\Folder\Example` as per [here](https://www.itworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html).

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue after I moved a project to another folder. In my case I closed VS renamed the .vs folder in root to 1.vs (effectively removing it) and re-opend my project.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was first trying to install a package using **`Manage Nuget Packages for Solutions`** and was getting this error. Then I tried installing same package using **`Package Manager Console`** and it worked fine. I again uninstalled that package and tried installing using **`Manage Nuget Packages for Solutions`** and this time it worked fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my experience all i had to do is move the entire project to my c: drive, delete unnecessary folders to ensure the path would be shorter. Done deal.

Comment: You missed the part that says " However due to a change in naming scheme from on high, the root directory for this project was changed from...". I don't have a choice as to where the source code is stored, that change came from higher up the food chain.

Comment: My solution is just a simple way to directly deal with the error, explained simply and to the point, I did, however, miss the part whereby user does not have a choice where source code is stored, infact it baffles me why this would be the case...??

Comment: To resolve this without moving your entire source code to another folder on your hard disk, you could just map a drive to the folder (or even a parent folder containing all your repos if that's suitable), and then open the solution file in VS directly from Explorer (it can't be opened via VS itself). To map a drive to a local folder, use `net use x: \\localhost\c$\Folder\Example` as per [here](https://www.itworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

This error comes to me when I tried to copy the project folder to OneDrive and the problem is that OneDrive is not uploading long name files.

I've fixed this issue by just copying the project folder then paste it in the new laptop using USB.

I wish this could help

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder of the project to a folder within a few levels from the root dir. For example the Desktop and voila.

Comment: To resolve this without moving your entire source code to another folder on your hard disk, you could just map a drive to the folder (or even a parent folder containing all your repos if that's suitable), and then open the solution file in VS directly from Explorer (it can't be opened via VS itself). To map a drive to a local folder, use `net use x: \\localhost\c$\Folder\Example` as per [here](https://www.itworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to close Solution from `File->Close Solution` and opening it again.

For my case uninstalling, installing, or even updating NuGet packages, nothing was working but reopening(sometimes you can also close and open Visual Studio again) the Solution did the magic.